# Unable to use vlc.net.forms.dll

Tags: vb.net, vlc, libvlc

I am using VB.Net. I am trying to use the vlc.net.forms.dll but I am unable to find any proper code. Can anyone provide me a complete code?
The kind of code I found does not work and some classes are missing like Core.Medias

This code is in C# and I can convert C#. So, if you have code in C#, you can also post that.

```
    bool replace = true;

if (vlcControl.Media != null)
{
if (vlcControl.IsPlaying)
    vlcControl.Stop();

if (MessageBox.Show("There is media loaded, do you wish to replace it?", "Media already loaded", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
    replace = false;
}

if (replace)
{
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
ofd.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*";
ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   var media = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.Medias.PathMedia(ofd.FileName);
   vlcControl.Media = media;
   vlcControl.Stop();
}
}
```

Comment: The code is in C#. Search on Google for "C# to VB.NET converter".

Comment: I know this is in C# and I can convert it. This C# code is incomplete.